# snap svg try to rotate an object with center point but not work

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I learn to use snap svg this library and want to rotate an object. However, I get a weird rotate effect and can't find what the problem is.

the following is the code snippet and you can have it a look.

```js
var s = Snap("#container"); 

//lets draw 2 rects at position 100,100 and then reposition them

var r = s.rect(100,100,100,100).attr({fill: 'red' });

var g = s.group(r);

var bbox = g.getBBox();


s.text(20, 20, bbox.cx);

s.text(20, 40, bbox.cy);

g.animate({ transform: 'r180,'+ bbox.cx + ',' + bbox.cy }, 1000, mina.bounce );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div style="width: 335px; height: 600px;">
  
    
    <svg width='100%' height='100%' id='container'></svg>
    
  </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope somebody can tell me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a bug in Snap 0.5/0.5.1 see [here](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/505).

First thing I would do, is try Snap 0.4.1 eg [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js) and see if that fixes it. I think it's fixed for 0.5.2, but not sure if that's available yet.

If it doesn't fix it, update the question to mention you have also tried 0.4.1.

Comment: yes...  that's a bug in snap 0.5.  I try the snippet with snap 0.4.1 and it works, lol.  thanks!